# Heroku/MongoLab not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I ma using heroku and mongolab to host my node app.
So far everything had been working great but now everytime I try to access my mongolab dashboard from heroku I get the following 500 error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed

type Exception report

message Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:482)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:137)
    org.objectlabs.http.RedirectValidatingHttpServletResponseWrapper.sendValidatedRedirect(RedirectValidatingHttpServletResponseWrapper.java:77)
    org.objectlabs.http.RedirectValidatingHttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(RedirectValidatingHttpServletResponseWrapper.java:51)
    org.owasp.csrfguard.http.InterceptRedirectResponse.sendRedirect(InterceptRedirectResponse.java:59)
    org.olabs.mongolabs.util.ErrorPage.doRedirectTo(ErrorPage.java:53)
    org.olabs.mongolabs.util.ErrorPage.redirectTo(ErrorPage.java:32)
    org.olabs.mongolabs.user.login.LoginGatekeeper.doFilter(LoginGatekeeper.java:63)
    org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:79)
    org.objectlabs.http.RedirectValidationFilter.doFilter(RedirectValidationFilter.java:20)
    org.objectlabs.http.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:23)
    org.objectlabs.http.ClickjackingProtectionFilter.doFilter(ClickjackingProtectionFilter.java:68)
    org.objectlabs.http.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:23)
    org.objectlabs.http.AddDefaultCharsetFilter.doFilter(AddDefaultCharsetFilter.java:50)
    ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:51)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
```

I am trying to access this url:

```
https://addons-sso.heroku.com/apps/my-app/addons/mongolab:sandbox
```

have I dont something wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the confusion. For your protection, we have expired all passwords after the heartbleed issue was announced this week and it appears that while you usually SSO in from Heroku you do actually have a password with us.

You appear to have hit an edge case with that code. You should be forced to your user info screen where you can update your password, but it appears you're tripping over an error. Could you write us at support@mongolab.com so that we can identify your account and work through the issue with you?